# Notepad++ syntax highlighting for *.map

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting, mapserver, map-files

I can't find how to customize syntax highlighting for mapfiles (*.map files) in Notepad++. I actually have add this [syntax file](https://sites.google.com/site/gianpierocampanella/files) recommended in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63139/notepad-syntax-highlighting-support-for-mapfiles). BUT the syntax highlighting is not good, probably because built for an old version of MapServer (see image below where plenty of key-words are not colored properly). I therefore have 2 questions:

1. How can I customize the syntax colorization? I can't access to the 'Mapfile' language via Settings > Style Configurator > Default theme (not in the languages list).
2. How is it possible to make Notepad++ recognize *.map files automatically? When I open such a file, it is colored like a txt file and the extension *.map is not recognized.

Many thanks for help!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure this has been answered somewhere over here or at [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com), can't find it right now.
Go to *Languages* > *Define Your language* > select your defined language from the *User Language* dropdown and set the *Ext* field with `map`.

I have this setup for *.log files :
[image: npp screenshot]

To update the highlighting rules select the tabs *Keywords Lists* , *Comment & Number* etc and update the rules.

Update --
Okay found it here : [How can I tell Notepad++ to always use a particular language with a particular file extension](https://superuser.com/questions/151597/how-can-i-tell-notepad-to-always-use-a-particular-language-with-a-particular-f?rq=1)

Comment: To @Shekhar : could you please have a quick look to this new post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164052/notepad-syntax-highlighting-conflict-in-rules) I sent concerning a highlighting rules conflict?