# Notepad++ syntax highlighting : conflict in rules

Tags: notepad++, syntax-highlighting, keyword

I have customized a new language in Notepad++.

My problem is that I have two keywords : `LAYER` and `LAYER_ENCODING`. In the menu *Languages > Define Your language > Select your defined language*, `LAYER` is mentionned in the first tab *Syntax folding* whereas `LAYER_ENCODING` is mentionned in the second tab *Keywords lists*. Here is the syntax coloration I get for `LAYER_ENCODING`:

[image]

I seems that `LAYER_ENCODING` keyword is not recognized because `LAYER` already exists... Any idea on how I could solve this problem?

**EDIT :** Here are my custom rules:

```
<NotepadPlus>
    <UserLang name="Mapfile" ext="map" udlVersion="2.1">
        <Settings>
            <Global caseIgnored="no" allowFoldOfComments="no" foldCompact="no" forcePureLC="0" decimalSeparator="0" />
            <Prefix Keywords1="no" Keywords2="no" Keywords3="no" Keywords4="no" Keywords5="no" Keywords6="no" Keywords7="no" Keywords8="no" />
        </Settings>
        <KeywordLists>
            <Keywords name="Comments">03 04 00# 01 02</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, prefix1"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, prefix2"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, extras1"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, extras2"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, suffix1"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, suffix2"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Numbers, range"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Operators1">&apos; ! &quot; $ % &amp; ( ) * , . / : ; ? @ [ \ ] ^ { | } ~ + &lt; = &gt;</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Operators2"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code1, open">MAP LINESET MARKERSET POINTS SHADESET STYLE CLASS FEATURE JOIN LABEL LAYER LEGEND PROJECTION GRID QUERY OUTPUTFORMAT QUERYMAP REFERENCE SCALEBAR WEB METADATA</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code1, middle"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code1, close">END</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code2, open"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code2, middle"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in code2, close"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in comment, open"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in comment, middle"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Folders in comment, close"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords1">FONTSET GRID OUTPUTFORMAT SYMBOLSET</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords2">ANGLE ANTIALIAS BACKGROUNDCOLOR BACKGROUNDSHADOWCOLOR BACKGROUNDSHADOWSIZE BUFFER CHARACTER CLASSITEM COLOR CONNECTION CONNECTIONTYPE CONFIG DATAPATTERN DATA DESCRIPTION DEBUG DRIVER DUMP EMPTY ERROR EXPRESSION EXTENT EXTENSION FILLED FONT FOOTER FORCE FROM FILTER FILTERITEM FORMATOPTION GROUP HEADER IMAGE IMAGECOLOR IMAGEPATH IMAGEURL INTERLACE INTERVALS IMAGETYPE IMAGEMODE INCLUDE KEYIMAGE KEYSIZE KEYSPACING LABELANGLEITEM LABELCACHE LABELITEM LABELMAXSCALE LABELMINSCALE LABELSIZEITEM LAYER_ENCODING LOG LABELREQUIRES LABELFORMAT MAXFEATURES MAXSCALE MAXSCALEDENOM MAXSIZE MAXTEMPLATE MINDISTANCE MINFEATURESIZE MINSCALE MINSIZE MINTEMPLATE MINARCS MAXARCS MININTERVAL MAXINTERVAL MINSUBDIVIDE MINWIDTH MAXSUBDIVIDE MAXWIDTH MIMETYPE MARKER MARKERSIZE MINBOXSIZE MAXBOXSIZE NAME OFFSET OUTLINECOLOR OFFSITE OVERLAYOUTLINECOLOR OVERLAYCOLOR OVERLAYSYMBOL OVERLAYSIZE OVERLAYMINSIZE OVERLAYMAXSIZE OVERLAYBACKGROUNDCOLOR PARTIALS POSITION POSTLABELCACHE PROCESSING QUERYITEM REQUIRES RESULT_FIELDS RESULT_HEADERS SCALE SHAPEPATH SIZE SPACING STATUS STYLED SYMBOL SYMBOLSCALE SYMBOLSCALEDENOM STYLEITEM SIZEUNITS SHADOWCOLOR SHADOWSIZE TABLE TEMPLATE TEXT TILEINDEX TILEITEM TO TOLERANCE TOLERANCEUNITS TRANSFORM TRANSPARENT TRANSPARENCY TYPE TEMPLATEPATTERN UNITS WRAP WIDTH</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords3">annotation auto bitmap cc cl cr dd default ddmm ddmmss embed ellipse embed epsg false feet giant gif gtiff hilite inches jpeg kilometers large lc line ll local lr medium meters miles multiple normal off on ogr pixmap pixels point polygon polyline png queryonly raster sde selected single small swf tiny true truetype uc ul ur vector wbmp wms wms_srs wms_name wms_server_version wms_format wms_connectiontimeout wms_latlonboundingbox wms_formatlist wms_style wms_time wms_force_separate_request</Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords4"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords5"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords6"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords7"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Keywords8"></Keywords>
            <Keywords name="Delimiters">00&quot; 01 02&quot; 03&apos; 04 05&apos; 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23</Keywords>
        </KeywordLists>
        <Styles>
            <WordsStyle name="DEFAULT" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="COMMENTS" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="LINE COMMENTS" fgColor="808080" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="NUMBERS" fgColor="FF0000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="Consolas" fontStyle="0" fontSize="12" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS1" fgColor="0000FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS2" fgColor="808000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS3" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS4" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS5" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS6" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS7" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS8" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="OPERATORS" fgColor="0000FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN CODE1" fgColor="0000FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN CODE2" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN COMMENT" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS1" fgColor="800040" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS2" fgColor="800000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS3" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS4" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS5" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS6" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS7" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
            <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS8" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontName="" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        </Styles>
    </UserLang>
</NotepadPlus>
```

Comment: can you export your custom rule and share it ?

Comment: I've just edited my post to include my custom rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move code folding `LAYER` to *folding in code 2 style*. Folding in code 2 style works [differently](http://udl20.weebly.com/folding-in-code.html) from the first which uses forward search and can glue to any other key words. Code style two honors white spaces and other special characters.

[image: code style screenshot]

[image: Code folding screenshot]

Comment: Thanks @Shekar! I have moved `LAYER` into *Folding in code 2* and add `END` into *Close* box. Result: `LAYER_ENCODING` is now colored green properly but `LAYER` is now black instead of blue as on your example...

Comment: @wiltomap click on the styler button and select blue and bold in the window that opens.